# Any guidance on float overs?

Tags: css, colors, tabs, hover

I found this tabbed content and so far set it up but for the life of me cannot figure out how to change the colour of the tab to a difference colour when you hover over it.

I thought it would be the tabs label:hover but it doesn't seem to be.

My code is here:

```
    body, html {
              height: 100%;
              margin: 0;
              -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
              font-weight: 100;
              background: #ffffff;
              text-align: center;
              font-family: helvetica;
          }

          .tabs input[type=radio] {
              position: absolute;
              top: -9999px;
              left: -9999px;
          }
          .tabs {
            width: 670px;
            float: none;
            list-style: none;
            position: relative;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 75px auto;
          }
          .tabs li{
            float: left;
          }
          .tabs label {
              display: block;
              padding: 10px 20px;
              border-radius: 0px 0px 0 0;
              color: #ffffff;
              font-size: 18px;
              font-weight: normal;
              font-family: helvetica;
              background: #f3f3f3;
              cursor: pointer;
              position: relative;
              top: 3px;
              -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
              -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
              -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
              transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
          }
          .tabs label:hover {
            background: #9eab05);
            top: 1px;
          }

     /* LABEL COLOURS */

          [id^=tab]:checked + label {
            background: #e3ba12;
            color: white;
            top: 0;
          }

          [id^=tabfindme]:checked + label {
            background: #e3ba12;
            color: white;
            top: 0;
          }
          [id^=tabtwitter]:checked + label {
            background: #0085a1;
            color: white;
            top: 0;
          }
          [id^=tabtv]:checked + label {
            background: #6a2150;
            color: white;
            top: 0;
          }
          [id^=tabteach]:checked + label {
            background: #d10373;
            color: white;
            top: 0;
          }       


          [id^=tab]:checked ~ [id^=tab-content] {
              display: block;
          }

     /* CONTENT COLOURS */

        .findmecontent{
            z-index: 2;
            display: none;
            text-align: left;
            width: 100%;
            font-size: 12px;
            line-height: 140%;
            padding-top: 0px;
            background: #e3ba12;
            padding: 15px;
            color: white;
            position: absolute;
            top: 40px;
            left: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
            -o-animation-duration: 0.5s;
            -moz-animation-duration: 0.5s;
            animation-duration: 0.5s; }
        .twittercontent{
            z-index: 2;
            display: none;
            text-align: left;
            width: 100%;
            font-size: 12px;
            line-height: 140%;
            padding-top: 0px;
            background: #0085a1;
            padding: 15px;
            color: white;
            position: absolute;
            top: 40px;
            left: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
            -o-animation-duration: 0.5s;
            -moz-animation-duration: 0.5s;
            animation-duration: 0.5s;
    }
        .tvcontent{
            z-index: 2;
            display: none;
            text-align: left;
            width: 100%;
            font-size: 12px;
            line-height: 140%;
            padding-top: 0px;
            background: #6a2150;
            padding: 15px;
            color: white;
            position: absolute;
            top: 40px;
            left: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
            -o-animation-duration: 0.5s;
            -moz-animation-duration: 0.5s;
            animation-duration: 0.5s;
    }
        .teachcontent{
            z-index: 2;
            display: none;
            text-align: left;
            width: 100%;
            font-size: 12px;
            line-height: 140%;
            padding-top: 0px;
            background: #d10373;
            padding: 15px;
            color: white;
            position: absolute;
            top: 40px;
            left: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
            -o-animation-duration: 0.5s;
            -moz-animation-duration: 0.5s;
            animation-duration: 0.5s;
    }

<ul class="tabs">
        <li>
        <input type="radio" checked name="tabs" id="tabfindme">
        <label for="tabfindme">FIND ME</label>
        <div id="tab-content1" class="findmecontent animated fadeIn">
         You can find me at the following venues:
            <ul>
                <li>BBC Television Centre</li>
                <li>OutBurst Festival</li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
        <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tabtwitter">
        <label for="tabtwitter">TWITTER</label>
        <div id="tab-content2" class="twittercontent animated fadeIn">
                Twitterfeed
        </div>
        </li>
        <li>
        <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tabtv">
        <label for="tabtv">TELEVISION</label>
        <div id="tab-content3" class="tvcontent animated fadeIn">
            Click the links to see me on TV
                <ul>
                    <li>BBC Television Centre</li>
                    <li>ITV</li>
                </ul>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li>
        <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tabteach">
        <label for="tabteach">HOW I TEACH</label>
        <div id="tab-content4" class="teachcontent animated fadeIn">
            How I teach
        </div>
        </li>

        </li>
```

Comment: I have updated the code with some slight tweaks to the text.  My final out come is when I hover the Find Me, the hover colour will be yellow, and when I click on it it will stay yellow.  And the Twitter, the hover will be blue and the tab will stay blue etc.

If you can advise again it's racking my brains.  I can do the above, but then loose the colour after clicking the tab, or the first tab is not yellow on load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use hover instead checked, example on the find me button

```
     [id^=tabfindme]:hover + label {
        background: red
        color: white;
        top: 0;
      }
```

Comment: Perfrect!  Now I need to figure out why that works :)

Comment: actually not quite, @faby works.  My only thing I cant do is for the float overs to be different colours, ie 1st tab is yellow, when I float over it will turn yellow, then when I click on it it will stay yellow.

Answer (score 2):

```
 .tabs label:hover {
            background: #9eab05;
            top: 1px;
          }
```

there is a ")" <-- remove it

fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/n5ura/

```
 body, html {
              height: 100%;
              margin: 0;
              -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
              font-weight: 100;
              background: #ffffff;
              text-align: center;
              font-family: helvetica;
          }

          .tabs input[type=radio] {
              position: absolute;
              top: -9999px;
              left: -9999px;
          }
          .tabs {
            width: 670px;
            float: none;
            list-style: none;
            position: relative;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 75px auto;
          }
          .tabs li{
            float: left;
          }
          .tabs label {
              display: block;
              padding: 10px 20px;
              border-radius: 0px 0px 0 0;
              color: #ffffff;
              font-size: 18px;
              font-weight: normal;
              font-family: helvetica;
              background: #f3f3f3;
              cursor: pointer;
              position: relative;
              top: 3px;
              -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
              -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
              -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
              transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
          }
          .tabs label:hover {
            background: #9eab05;
            top: 1px;
          }

     /* LABEL COLOURS */

          [id^=tab]:checked + label {
            background: #e3ba12;
            color: white;
            top: 0;
          }

          [id^=tabfindme]:checked + label {
            background: #e3ba12;
            color: white;
            top: 0;
          }
          [id^=tabtwitter]:checked + label {
            background: #0085a1;
            color: white;
            top: 0;
          }
          [id^=tabtv]:checked + label {
            background: #6a2150;
            color: white;
            top: 0;
          }
          [id^=tabteach]:checked + label {
            background: #d10373;
            color: white;
            top: 0;
          }       


          [id^=tab]:checked ~ [id^=tab-content] {
              display: block;
          }

     /* CONTENT COLOURS */

        .findmecontent{
            z-index: 2;
            display: none;
            text-align: left;
            width: 100%;
            font-size: 12px;
            line-height: 140%;
            padding-top: 0px;
            background: #e3ba12;
            padding: 15px;
            color: white;
            position: absolute;
            top: 40px;
            left: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
            -o-animation-duration: 0.5s;
            -moz-animation-duration: 0.5s;
            animation-duration: 0.5s; }
        .twittercontent{
            z-index: 2;
            display: none;
            text-align: left;
            width: 100%;
            font-size: 12px;
            line-height: 140%;
            padding-top: 0px;
            background: #0085a1;
            padding: 15px;
            color: white;
            position: absolute;
            top: 40px;
            left: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
            -o-animation-duration: 0.5s;
            -moz-animation-duration: 0.5s;
            animation-duration: 0.5s;
    }
        .tvcontent{
            z-index: 2;
            display: none;
            text-align: left;
            width: 100%;
            font-size: 12px;
            line-height: 140%;
            padding-top: 0px;
            background: #6a2150;
            padding: 15px;
            color: white;
            position: absolute;
            top: 40px;
            left: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
            -o-animation-duration: 0.5s;
            -moz-animation-duration: 0.5s;
            animation-duration: 0.5s;
    }
        .teachcontent{
            z-index: 2;
            display: none;
            text-align: left;
            width: 100%;
            font-size: 12px;
            line-height: 140%;
            padding-top: 0px;
            background: #d10373;
            padding: 15px;
            color: white;
            position: absolute;
            top: 40px;
            left: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
            -o-animation-duration: 0.5s;
            -moz-animation-duration: 0.5s;
            animation-duration: 0.5s;
    }
```

Comment: just about what I want.  I am after the hover colour to be the yellow for the first, blue for the second etc.  But thank you so far!

Answer (score 1):

maybe change this ?

```
  .tabs label:hover {
            background: #9eab05;
            top: 1px;
          }
```

into :

```
.tabs label:hover {
            background: #9eab05;
            color:#000;
            top: 1px;
          }
```

if you want to change the color of the text. Or else change background into something else.

Comment: Not quite what I was after but it taught me something!  Thank you!